# How to add a js script as type="module"

Tags: javascript, 9

How to add **type="module"** to script added in ***MODULENAME.libraries.yml*** when i do:

```
my-library:
  version: 1.x
  js:
    js/App.js: { }
```

I get

```
<script src="/modules/custom/MODULENAME/js/App.js?v=1.x"></script>
```

I need to add **type="module"** to script tag like:

```
<script type="module" src="/modules/custom/MODULENAME/js/App.js?v=1.x"></script>
```

I have tried:

```
my-library:
  version: 1.x
  js:
    js/App.js: { type: module }
```

But i doesn’t work.
Is this possible to add a script of type module?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, with the *attributes* property.

```yaml
my-library:
  version: 1.x
  js:
    js/App.js: { attributes: { type: module } }
```

See [Adding attributes to script elements](https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-theme#s-adding-attributes-to-script-elements) and [JS properties](https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-theme#js-properties).